# Providing clickAction to viewPager

Tags: android, onclick, android-viewpager

I have used the android v4 viewPager widget. I want to go to a different page when i click on the current page of the viewpager. I tried using setOnClickListener. But this action is not being listened. When i use setOnTouchListener, this works but the swipe action disappears!The page is being inflated with a relative layout with textviews
Please see the code snippet:

```
    mInfoPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.info_pager);
    mInfoPager.setClickable(true);
    mInfoPager = new InfoPagerAdapter(InfoScreen.this,5);
    mInfoPager.setAdapter(mInfoPagerAdapter);
```

..

```
    mInfoPager.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Not coming here??

        }
    });
```

Comment: Same issue. Can't get onClick triggered on the ViewPager...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i suggest you to put the OnClickListener to the Views you put in the ViewPager and call
a function in the ViewPager so it can scroll left/right - this may works ;)